# Formatting and Readability of Output in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, output, readability

So I'm just learning Hadoop and trying out the WordCount.java tutorial which works fine. I have zero problems with it. My only issue is that when I get my results in the output file, I want to add in Strings myself. So lets say I have another file I read in, I want it to be readable eg.

```
========= Output 1 =========
// Results here
============================

========= Output 2 =========
// 2nd Results here
============================
```

Rather than

```
// Results here
// More results
```

I essentially just want to be able to send an output one time to the output file. What is the best place/way to do this? I'm guessing it would be in the main but I'm not sure. Is hadoop designed (used?) for this or should I used some kind of bash script to work on making the output file pretty?

Code below,

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;

import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.*;

public class WordCount {

public static class Map extends MapReduceBase implements Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {
  private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
  private Text word = new Text();

  public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
    String line = value.toString();
    StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line);
    while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
      word.set(tokenizer.nextToken());
      output.collect(word, one);
    }
  }
}

public static class Reduce extends MapReduceBase implements Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {
  public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<IntWritable> values, OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
    int sum = 0;
    while (values.hasNext()) {
      sum += values.next().get();
    }
    output.collect(key, new IntWritable(sum));
  }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  JobConf conf = new JobConf(WordCount.class);
  conf.setJobName("wordcount");

  conf.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
  conf.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

  conf.setMapperClass(Map.class);
  conf.setCombinerClass(Reduce.class);
  conf.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);

  conf.setInputFormat(TextInputFormat.class);
  conf.setOutputFormat(TextOutputFormat.class);

  FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(conf, new Path(args[0]));
  FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf, new Path(args[1]));

  JobClient.runJob(conf);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe I can use [NullWritable](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/io/NullWritable.html) for this. If there's a better way though please do post an answer.